# Distance perpendicular to motion in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity

Is there an easy way to see why two observers whose relative motion is confined to the $x$ axis will agree on the $y$ components of distance?

I'm looking for something a little less hand-wavey than just saying "because of symmetry." Ideally, it would **not** depend on the derivation of the rest of the Lorentz Transformation. That said, if it has to depend on it, it can.

Here is a starting point, which may or may not be on the right track:

Observers $O$ and $O'$ start at the origin at time $t=0$. According to $O$, $O'$ is moving with velocity $v$ in the $x$ direction. Also at time $t=0$, a flash of light is released at a location 1 light-second away from $O$, in the $y$ direction. So after 1 second, measured by a clock that $O$ is holding, $O$ will see the light flash.

If there were a simple way to see that $O'$ will also see the light flash after 1 second, measured by a clock she is holding, I think that would answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ and $B$ are in motion with respect to each other in the $x$ direction.  They're each holding meter sticks oriented in the $y$ direction.    Each meter stick has, mounted at each end, a ballpoint pen pointing in the $z$ direction.

If $A$ says that $B$'s stick is, say, two inches shorter than his own, then, when the ship's pass, $A$ will say that $B$'s pens can leave simultaneous marks on $A$'s stick, say one inch in from each edge.  $B$ can see these marks and therefore must agree with $A$ that his stick is shorter than $A$'s by two inches.

Answer (score 1):

As WillO has demonstrated, 'transverse length contraction', if it occurred, would in principle be demonstrable. But then frame B would be distinguishable from frame A as the frame in which transverse lengths were contracted; it wouldn't be the case that the contraction is mutual. So the Relativity Principle (indistinguishability of frames) would be violated. Although this is admitttedly a symmetry argument, I don't think it's hand-wavy!

[Note that 'longitudinal length contraction' doesn't violate the Relativity Principle because (essentially) the lengths are measured using different procedures in the two frames.]

Comment: Hope the reference to another answer doesn't fall foul of the guidelines. Please be charitable.

Answer (score 0):

If a particle is moving along the x-axis and it's velocity increases then it'll only see the world around it be contracted in the x-axis. It won't see any contraction in the y or z axises. This is due to how length contraction works. A particle will only see length contraction occurring in the axis of relative motion.